# Laravel 9.x - Class binding not working in middleware

Tags: laravel, request, middleware

i am having issue in my laravel middleware.

i try to extends Illuminate\Http\Request to my custom class request

```
<?php

namespace LaravelCommon\Http\Request;

use App\Repositories\User\TokenRepository;
use Illuminate\Http\Request as HttpRequest;

class MyRequest extends HttpRequest {
....
```

then bind it in AppServiceProvider

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;
....
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public $bindings = [
        Request::class => MyRequest::class // this the class i want to extends
    ];
```

i create middleware to get MyRequest in parameter 1

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use LaravelCommon\Http\Request\MyRequest;
use LaravelCommon\Responses\BaseResponse;

class ControllerAfter
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \LaravelCommon\Http\Request\MyRequest  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(MyRequest $request, Closure $next)
    {
```

but i got some error says

```
TypeError
Argument 1 passed to LaravelCommon\App\Http\Middleware\ControllerAfter::handle() 
must be an instance of LaravelCommon\Http\Request\MyRequest, 
instance of Illuminate\Http\Request given, called in 
/srv/www/PHP/laravelBP/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php
on line 167
```

all i know that AppServiceProvider::$bindings will resolve the class binding in any type-hint we use somewhere. but in my case the parameter 1 still got Illuminate\Http\Request.

did i mistaken how i bind the class? or any other way to solve this?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow andik. just to be sure, the `AppServiceProvider` is registered in `config/app.php` right?

Comment: surely, this is a new fresh install, didnt change anything in any place, just need to extends the Illuminate\Http\Request. any idea to achieve this?